# With comma as decimal separator, how do you insert a period in the header/footer?

Tags: front-end, customization, printing

I have enabled comma as my decimal separator, which means that comma still acts normally and when pressing period it will be converted to a comma.

In the header I would like to make a period, so I insert a period and it looks like a period, however when I view the print preview, the period is converted to a comma.

How do I keep this from happening or is there a special period character that doesn't get converted to a comma?

Alternatively how can I make the header plain text, as this behavior doesn't occur in plain text mode?

---

**Edit:** Answering @SjoerdC.deVries questions:

1. With header I mean the option you set with `File > Printing Settings > Headers and Footers...`
2. The setting to change the decimal separator was found in Mathematica under `Preferences > Appearance > Numbers > Formatting > Decimal point character`
3. The period is the normal period key, not one on the keypad, although I would think they act similar.

Comment: A few questions to make your question a little bit more specific: 1. With "header" you mean the page header which you set with `File>`Printing Settings>Headers and Footers...`? 2. The setting of comma as decimal separator did you do that within Mathematica's preferences (tab Appearance/Numbers) or on OS level or both? 3. Do you press the period on your numeric keypad or on the main keyboard?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Updated question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The period in the header remains as a period even though I changed the decimal separator to a comma. I'm using mma 8.04 on Mac OS 10.8. What's yours?

Comment: If i recall correctly, on Windows the period on the keypad can be made to act as a decimal comma while the period on the main keyboard still produces a period.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 8.0 on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Comment: Do you use the period to end a sentence or is this in an expression? If in an expression, I guess a workaround would be to use "." and `StringJoin`-ing this with the other parts of your expression.

Comment: Can't reproduce this on Windows either.

Comment: It is in the middle of a word, in this case: `2.n`

Comment: I don't have a clue actually. Anything else out of the ordinary that you may have done? Where and how did you enter this word precisely?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Nope and in the dialog under Header and Middle.

Comment: So, you just entered 2.n and nothing else in the empty bar below the left, center, right buttons? What happens when you enter 2.n in a header in a program like MS Word?

Comment: It would display "2.n" in Word, and it also displays as "2.n" when entering it in the Mathematica header, however when saving as PDF or printing it appear as "2,n" in the header.